# how to create IC_launcher vector file in android studio?

Tags: java, xml, android-studio

I accidentally deleted my ic_laucher vector file, due to which it is showing an error. Can anyone tell me how to recreate it?
I'm using android studio IDE.

[image: Here's the error caused by this]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on the `res` folder in your project:

[image]

This will open a dialog like this, with which you can create a new one:

[image]